# MYSQL get total sum and sum between 2 date in 1 query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the total sum of a column and the sum of the same column between 2 dates in one query. is this possible?

My table looks like this:

```
uid|amount|date
```

The two queries i am trying to make one of:

```
SELECT sum(amount) as `keys` FROM tbl_keys WHERE uid = 1

SELECT sum(amount) as `keys` FROM tbl_keys WHERE uid = 1 AND YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
AND MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a UNION query:

```
SELECT 'All' AS cnt, sum(amount) as `keys` FROM tbl_keys WHERE uid = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Current_month' AS cnt, sum(amount) as `keys`
FROM tbl_keys
WHERE
  uid = 1
  AND `date`<= last_day(current_date)
  `date`>= current_date - interval (day(current_date)-1) day
```

(I prefer to use `>=` and `<=` on the date column, as it can make use of an index if present, while functions like `MONTH()` or `YEAR()` cannot, also I assume that `date` is a date columnd and that it doesn't contain time informations).

If you want the result in one row, you could use an inline query:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT sum(amount) as `keys` FROM tbl_keys WHERE uid = 1) AS total,
  (SELECT sum(amount) as `keys`
   FROM tbl_keys
   WHERE
     uid = 1
     AND `date`<= last_day(current_date)
    `date`>= current_date - interval (day(current_date)-1) day
   ) AS current_month
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT sum(amount) as `keys`,
(
    SELECT sum(t.amount)
    FROM tbl_keys as t 
    WHERE t.uid = tbl_keys.uid AND YEAR(t.`date`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
    AND MONTH(t.`date`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
) as `keys2`
FROM tbl_keys 
WHERE uid = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sum(amount) AS `keys`
FROM (
SELECT amount FROM tbl_keys
UNION ALL
SELECT amount FROM tbl_keys
WHERE uid = 1 
AND YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
AND MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
) AS new_table;
```

Using a `UNION` clause, you will get the desired output you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE to count only the amount for the specified date:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS `keys`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
        AND MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'keys2'
    FROM tbl_keys
    WHERE uid = 1
;
```

My guess is that this will run more efficient than a solution using UNION SELECT.